# Deployment failed from bitbucket to Azure Web App. Access Denied Error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket

Right now whenever something is merged to master branch in bitbucket it triggers a build in azure. It was working fine until yesterday. But now when I deploy anything build is failing on Azure.

Getting this error:

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling ASP.NET
> Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild16.7.0. Access is denied.
> Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuilds\16.8.3\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /restore
> "D:\home\site\repository\Demo.Test\Demo.Test.csproj"
> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration=Release
> /p:publishurl="D:\local\Temp\8xddxxxxx" An error has occurred during
> web site deployment. Access is denied.\r\nD:\Program Files
> (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\94.30524.5227\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
> "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try restarting your app.
On the Azure Portal, on your app’s blade, you have the options to stop or restart your app.
If you make any changes in bitbucket ,
In Azure portal -- > Deployment Center, make sure to sync to reflect the changes.
Then try to restart the App Service

For Reference please go through the given Link
https://codeindarkmode.wordpress.com/2020/06/06/publishing-web-application-to-azure-web-app/